# How good or bad of a fit would this question about international human rights law have been here?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

I just asked a question at Expatriates SE called

[Could one renounce one's native citizenship in order to prevent a second, naturalized citizenship from being revoked?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/11767/9674)

I contemplated posting it on another SE instead, for example Politics SE or Law SE.

Would it have fit better (or worse) here?

Comment: I think it would be a good fit, except that the answer is "who knows?" unless you specify jurisdictions. E.g. there is a real problem for Iranians in Japan because Japan requires a choice, and Iran effectively prohibits renunciation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like it would be more on-topic here, since it is specifically about actual laws and treaties constraining the actions of governments.